# How Can I run my CURL in php with htaccess rule RewriteRule ^/?.*$ “http\:\/\/127\.0\.0\.1” [R,L]

Tags: php, .htaccess, curl, bots

I have these lines in .htaccess but it also stopped my curl script in php.
Can anyone let me know how i can run curl in page with said rule?

Thanks

PS: I have these lines.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (bot|crawl|robot)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(bing|Google|msn|MSR|Twitter|Yandex) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?.*$ “http\:\/\/127\.0\.0\.1” [R,L]
```

Comment: Show your curl script